AWS Sagemaker asynchronous endpoint upload timeout
I'm using a Sagemaker asynchronous endpoint configured to upload the inference result (a txt file) to a bucket S3.
When the total size of the files to upload is less then ~300kb it works fine, otherwise i get an error in the model logs asserting that the upload operation timed out.
Timed out uploading object (bucket: <bucket name>, key: model/failure/720563d2-55db-49ae-8d9b-96e8cc6ef90b-error.out).
Note that the inference itself runs to completion with no errors, it's just the upload on s3 that is not working.
According to the doc, there isn't a configuration setting to control that.

300kb is not a upper limit of the output files that can be uploaded, I've personally had multiple MBs .out files done without failure. I would recommend opening a support case with SageMaker Endpoint ARN and timestamp of the issue to look at the logs from our end.

Thank you, in fact i found that if i use a dummy endpoint that just upload the files there are no issues. I think that it is linked to the inference timeout, it's just a uninformative error message.

Hey, I'm having the same issue. Did you end up finding a solution?

Hi  @yohairosen we added the param InvocationTimeouSeconds to the invoke_endpoint_async of the boto3 client:
 response = sagemaker_runtime.invoke_endpoint_async(                 EndpointName=INFERENCE_ENDPOINT,                 InvocationTimeoutSeconds=3600,                 InputLocation=f's3://{S3_BUCKET}/{s3_key}',                 CustomAttributes=json.dumps(context))

@Daniele works like magic. You are a life saver!
